# how to concatenate two text values and pass to hidden text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have different task to do.

```
<input type='hidden' id='company' value='testing'>
<input type='text' id='username' value=''>
<input type='hidden' id='company_username' value='testing+ username'>
```

Here i have three fields. I want to combine company value (hidden) with username what ever user type is shown.
I want combine this two fields and pass to company_username field which is also hidden and send data to database.

Is there any solution to solve this fields 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you want to concatenate these 2 elements and store in third hidden element ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#username").focusout(function(){
    $("#company_username").val('testing');
    var   a= $(this).val();
   $("#company_username").val($("#company_username").val()+"+"+a);
     console.log($("#company_username").val());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='hidden' id='company' value='testing'>
<input type='text' id='username' value=''>
<input type='hidden' id='company_username' value='testing'>
```